# Why does the "printing neatly" algorithm use cubes rather than squares?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, cubics, dynamic-programming

In *Introduction to Algorithms*, 2nd ed. (Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, and Stein), ch. 15, *Dynamic Programming*, problem 15-2 *Printing neatly* (a copy of which is 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979498/algorithm-for-neatly-printing-a-paragraph-on-a-printer)), the official solution given in *Instructor's Manual to Accompany Introduction to Algorithms, Second Edition*, is an algorithm that minimizes the extra spaces at the ends of lines ***cubed***.

My question is: why *cubed*? Why not squared? Or some other power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used first powers, it would have no selectivity as the total number of spaces at the ends of lines is just the length of a line times the number of lines minus the length of the text.  As you increase the power, you penalize large gaps at the end of the line more.  It is really a question of taste.  Would you rather have gaps of $10,1,1,1,1,1,1$ or $0,8,0,0,8,0,0?$  Cubes will pick the second and squares the first.

Comment: So if you were to increase the power to 4, 5, or more, I imagine that there's a point beyond which it no longer matters (diminishing returns)?

Comment: Yes. If the power gets very high, you will only care about the largest value, so $9,9,9,9,9$ and lots of$1$s will beat $10$ and lots more $1$s